# Get months between two dates in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have a function that returns the following:

```
Title     Start          End
Task A    2015-01-02     2015-03-31
Task B    2015-02-12     2015-04-01
Task C    2014-11-01     2015-02-05
....
```

I want to return a column for each month and 1 if its within the Start and End period 0 otherwise

```
 Title     Start          End          Jan   Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  ....
 Task A    2015-01-02     2015-03-31    1     1    1    0    0    0
 Task B    2015-02-12     2015-04-01    0     1    1    1    0    0 
 Task C    2014-11-01     2015-02-05    1     1    0    0    0    0
 ....
```

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: What you are asking is called PIVOT tables. If you look a little bit you will find your answer. Or at least how to start to solve your problem, then if you still can't post the query you tried and we will help you to fix it

Comment: Is it possible for the starting and ending dates to be in different years or are you constraining the query to a single year?

Comment: It's not pivot tables.  I don't have data such as Jan, Feb etc to pivot across. Just have to create the columns based on the Start and End dates

Comment: When you create the monthly data you will have those rows to pivot. You have to do that step, but if you want those rows into columns, you're gonna have to pivot, there's no other way.

Comment: The dates are within one year (2015 as in this example).  Can assume that Jan, Feb... columns are fixed

Comment: You mean you ALWAYS have all twelve months in the result?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if google "dynamic sql pivot" you'll find what you're looking for.  If not, you can always create each of the month columns with a CASE statement.

Comment: The start and end date could change (e.g Task C) but Jan - Dec columns should reflect only the current year's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with basic `case` statements:

```
select title, start, end,
       (case when 1 between month(start) and month(end) then 1 else 0 end) as jan,
       (case when 2 between month(start) and month(end) then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
       . . .
       (case when 12 between month(start) and month(end) then 1 else 0 end) as dec
from table t;
```

Note:  I am leaving your column names as in the query, even though some are reserved words and should be escaped (if that is the real name of the columns).

Also note that in your sample data, the dates change between the first table and the second.

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanted to check 1 date, this would work.  You should be able to adapt this sample to meet your needs.

```
SELECT c.CreateDateUTC, DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC) 'MONTH',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 
    END 'JAN',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 2 THEN 1 
    END 'FEB',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 3 THEN 1 
    END 'MAR',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 4 THEN 1 
    END 'APR',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 5 THEN 1 
    END 'MAY',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 6 THEN 1 
    END 'JUN',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 7 THEN 1 
    END 'JUL',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 8 THEN 1 
    END 'AUG',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 9 THEN 1 
    END 'SEP',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 10 THEN 1 
    END 'OCT',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 11 THEN 1 
    END 'NOV',
    CASE DATEPART(MONTH, c.CreateDateUTC)
    WHEN 12 THEN 1 
    END 'DEC'   
FROM dbo.Code c
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To expand, make sure you check for null, and you can use ISNULL(StartDate,GetDate()) which will give you today if that fits your range needs.

```
select *, 
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 1 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Jan,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 2 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Feb,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 3 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Mar,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 4 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Apr,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 5 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end May,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 6 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Jun,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 7 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Jul,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 8 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Aug,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 9 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Sep,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 10 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Oct,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 11 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Nov,
    case when StartDate is not null and EndDate is not null and 12 between MONTH(StartDate) and Month(EndDate) then 1 else 0 end Dec
from Foo
```

Comment: The IS NOT NULL checks are redundant here. They will not be evaluated to be between the dates when the value is NULL.